# How do I connect to a postgresql database using python if the password contains "@" which is also a separator?

Tags: python, postgresql, passwords, connector

I'm trying to connect with no success to a postgresql database but the password containes "@" which is also a separator.

```
import pandas as pd
import connectorx as cx
import psycopg2

postgres_url = "postgresql://username:~2m4\9#T3(*4p**@**KL@aaa-aaaa.s111111111111.aws-emea.aaa.com:5432/bbb"

query = "select * from table1"

df = cx.read_sql(postgres_url, query)

df.head()
```

How can I overcome this?
Thank you.

Comment: Percent encode the `@` as `%40`  e.g. `~2m4\9#T3(*4p**%40**KL` per instruction here [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING): *34.1.1.2. Connection URIs  ... The connection URI needs to be encoded with percent-encoding if it includes symbols with special meaning in any of its parts.  ...*

Comment: I tried your way but unfortunately it is not working

Comment: Then something else is interfering as using it in  `psycopg2`  directly works; `con = psycopg2.connect("postgresql://aklaver:ranger%40dog@localhost:5432/test") con.status 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

> from urllib.parse import quote_plus
>
> password = "~2m4\9#T3(*4p@KL" encoded_password = quote_plus(password)
>
> postgres_url = "postgresql://username:" + encoded_password +
> "@aaa-aaaa.s111111111111.aws-emea.aaa.com:5432/bbb"
>
> query = "select * from table1"
>
> df = cx.read_sql(postgres_url, query)
>
> df.head()